# Terminating an std::thread which runs in endless loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

How can I terminate my spun off thread in the destructor of Bar (without having to wait until the thread woke up form its sleep)?

```
class Bar {

public:

Bar() : thread(&Bar:foo, this) {
}

~Bar() { // terminate thread here}



...

void foo() {
  while (true) {
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(
     std::chrono::seconds(LONG_PERIOD));

    //do stuff//
   }

}

private:
  std::thread thread;

};
```

Comment: Can you sleep with a timed condition wait instead of a hard sleep?

Comment: Use a [`condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: You can't terminate it externally but you can detach it.

Comment: You can change `while (true) {` with a `while (isDone) {` where `isDone` is a member `atomic<bool>` variable.

Comment: @ NathanOliver But if I detach it and the thread accesses member fields of Bar the behaviour would be undefined after the Bar instance gets destructed

Comment: @user695652: You will have to wait, until `LONG_PERIOD` has timed out. However, with a condition variable, you can prevent the thread from doing any work thereafter. While that solves half of your previous issue, you now have created a new one: How do you know, that your thread wasn't in the middle of processing data, when detaching from it? Maybe you can come up with a solution based on weak pointers (that are invalidated on `Bar` destruction).

Comment: @ zahir but then, worst case it takes time LONG_PERIOD to destruct Bar

Comment: @user695652 A  `std::atomic<bool>` member used as condition in the while loop should work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think the OP is saying that `LONG_PERIOD` is a couple hours so even if you use an `std::atomic<bool>` the thread could live a long time after its desired termination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):

```
class Bar {
public:   
    Bar() : t_(&Bar::foo, this) { }
    ~Bar() { 
        {
            // Lock mutex to avoid race condition (see Mark B comment).
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_);
            // Update keep_ and notify the thread.
            keep_ = false;
        } // Unlock the mutex (see std::unique_lock)
        cv_.notify_one();
        t_.join(); // Wait for the thread to finish
    }

    void foo() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_);
        while (keep_) {
            if (cv_.wait_for(lk, LONG_PERIOD) == std::cv_status::no_timeout) {
                continue; // On notify, just continue (keep_ is updated).
            }   
            // Do whatever the thread needs to do...
        }
    }

private:
    bool keep_{true};
    std::thread t_;
    std::mutex m_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
};
```

This should give you a global idea of what you may do:

- You use an `bool` to control the loop (with protected read and write access using a `std::mutex`);
- You use an `std::condition_variable` to wake up the thread to avoid waiting `LONG_PERIOD`.

Comment: Doesn't this have a race condition if you: (2) check keep, (1) set keep false, (1) notify_one, (2) acquire lock, (2) wait (LONG_PERIOD) for notify?

Comment: @MarkB Possibly... This is to give a broad idea, I'll update the code when I can.

Comment: The dtor needs to release the mutex, or the CV's wait in the other thread will never wake up. And since all access to `keep_` is done while the mutex is locked, it doesn't need to be atomic.

Comment: @Holt thanks for your answer. I have one question: What do you mean by You use an std::atomic<bool> to control the loop;?

Comment: @user695652 As written by T.C., you do not need `std::atomic` here since all read/write to the variable `keep_` are already protected by the mutex `m_`. I was using a `std::atomic` initially (which is why this is mentioned at the end - will update) because I was not locking `m_` in the destructor, which could create race issue (see Mark B comment above).

Comment: @ Holt thanks for the clarification. One more question: you have a continue(); inside the while(true) loop, shouldn't this line be replaces with whatever work one wants to execute in the thread?

Comment: @user695652 No, the condition is that there were no timeout, or otherwise said, the condition variable was notified. What you want your thread to execute should be after the `}` of this `if` (will edit to make it clearer).

Comment: Thanks a lot, so we don't even need the keep_ bool anymore?

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for pointing out the lock race, I should avoid updating answer while doing something else... ;) Could you give your opinion on the version without `keep_`? Seems better to me, but I would not want to miss something...

Comment: No. Two words: spurious wakeup.

Comment: @user695652 Do not use the version without `keep_`, see T.C.'s comments.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I was not aware of that.

Comment: OK, now just minor nits: 1) the dtor can notify without holding the lock. 2) There doesn't seem to be a point in locking and unlocking the mutex every iteration in `foo`. 3) Using the predicate version of `wait_for` is probably better style.

Comment: @T.C. 1) You mean releasing `m_` (`}`) after setting `keep_` to `false`? Or not locking `m_` at all in the dtor (which goes back to Mark B comment above)? 2) Declaring `lk` at the beginning of `foo` (and using `while (keep_)`)? Thanks.

Comment: Set `keep_` under the lock - you have to do that. But the `notify_one` is better done outside it.

Comment: `while(!cv.wait_for(lk, LONG_PERIOD, [this] { return !keep_; })) { /* stuff */ }`